# How to change function arguments in C?

Tags: c, algorithm, function, arguments

Inside a C function I am basically trying to convert all the values of the func argument into uppercase. Then use that *argument* somewhere else in the function. I **don't** want to change the variable passed into the function. Just the argument locally. Argument is an array of chars.

Here is what I tried:

```
int calculate_score(char *word[])
{
    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(word); i < n; i++)
    {
     if (islower(word[i]) != 0)
     {
        //this piece of code is not working
         toupper(word[i]);
     }
    }
```

How do I achieve this ?

**EDIT**: *I have included all the necessary header files string and ctype for this to work*

Comment: Where did you define `n`?

Comment: `toupper(word[i])` **returns** the uppercase letter.

Comment: `char *word[]` probably doesn't make sense. Why did you use that type of parameter? Is this an array of strings or a single string?

Comment: @Lundin An array of alphabets makes a word.

Comment: @user3386109 it returns but I am using word array in other parts of my code as well so best if we could modify it.

Comment: @Mike n is just defined in the loop. Its just storing the length of words array.

Comment: @Saswat "An array of alphabets makes a word"  I'm even more confused now... Do you mean an array of _characters_? That is: a null-terminated string?

Comment: @Lundin I am new to C. I didn't knew all of these terms. As you might guess C doesn't have  a built in string data type. words is an array of characters with null terminated('\0') as well. With that I loop over the characters and try to make the characters uppercase while still being able to use the modified array into other parts of my function.

Comment: What you have declared is _an array of pointers_ which is suitable in case you have an array of strings. If you were rather aiming to write a function dealing with _an array of characters_ - a single string, then your function parameter has the wrong type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to change the argument string, you should make a copy for local use:

- if there is a reasonable maximum length for this string, you can use a local array of `char` ;
- otherwise you can allocate memory for the copy and
- use a loop to convert the contents to upper case
- and free this copy before returning (if it was allocated)

Note that the argument should not be `char *word[]`, but `char *word` or better `const char *word`.

Here is an example:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int calculate_score(const char *word) {
    int res = 0;
    size_t i, n = strlen(word);
    char *copy = malloc(n + 1);
    if (copy == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "calculate_score: allocation error\n");
        return -1;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        unsigned char c = word[i];
        copy[i] = (char)toupper(c);
    }
    copy[i] = '\0';
    // use copy for the computation
    [...]
    free(copy);
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change the string passed into your function, make a *copy of it* and work on that.

```
void foo(char *bar) {
    char *s = strdup(bar);

    // do something to s
    // bar remains unchanged

    // don't forget to free that memory.
    free(s);
}
```

Comment: To make it more obvious that the argument string is not changed, you should change the prototype to `void foo(const char *bar)`.

Comment: @Chris: Words is an **array** How do I copy that?